# Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Tengo este mensaje de un `warning`, aunque ya he hecho el cambio aun me sigue apareciendo cada vez que compilo o inicio el proyecto, tal vez halla que hacer alguna corrección adicional, pero me gustaría que no me siga apareciendo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muestro gradle nivel app.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tics.uniagustiniana"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 6
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

//noinspection GradleCompatible
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

}apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

El gradle del proyecto está así.

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
    }
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    }
  task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
```

Comment: creo que se produce en el gradle del proyecto

Comment: @JulianYbarra tambien lo agregué a la pregunta, sin embargo no veo que ajustar allí, aunque esto no impide que ejecute la aplicación, siempre me lo muestra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actualiza com.google.gms:google-services de 3.1.1 a 3.2.0 y la advertencia dejara de aparecer.

Cambia la linea de

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

por

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

**ACTUALIZACION**

ir actualizando a medida que vayan saliendo nuevas actualizaciones de `com.google.gms:google-services`

Comment: Muchas gracias @Julian